# inserting directly php arrays from a form

Tags: php, arrays, insert

is it possible to insert an arrays to a php file directly without the need of a database. ie mysql.

the code would be like this:

```
<?php
$users = array();
$users["stephanie"] = array(
"first name" => "Stephanie",
"city" => "Greater London",
);
// << insert new records here after this. **is it Possible?** >>
?>
<form method="POST">
<p>Name: <input type="text" name="name"></p>
<p>City: <input type="text" name="city"></p>
</form>
```

Inserting directly from the form above. is it possible

Comment: What do you want in this??

Comment: You can use session..

Comment: if so how does one insert it to the array collection above?

Comment: your question is unclear. do u want to store data in files instead of database?

Comment: yes storing the data in a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it something like this.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['name'])){
    $users = array();
    $users[$_POST['name']] = array(
    "first name" => $_POST['name'],
    "city" => $_POST['city'],
    );
print_r($users);
}
// << Put insert records here. I don't know how you want to put it and why you need arrays. >>
?>
<form method="POST" action="index.php">  
<p>Name: <input type="text" name="name"></p>
<p>City: <input type="text" name="city"></p>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks i was following the mongodb principle by setting the database name. obviously it did not work by trying in the following format.
    insert->array([$_POST["name"] ... and so on.

Comment: just read your annotated comment. the aim was to store each inserted user detail, stored in the lines below.